# Can I group by first two characters of a column in sql using rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

**Preface:**

- The following is a rails sql query that allows me to find the 5 most frequent book searches in the last week, grouped by a few things.

```rb
time_range = (Time.now - 7.day)..Time.now

frequent = BookSearch.select("count(book_id) as id_count, short_name, isbn, genre").limit(5).where(created_at: time_range).group(:short_name).group(:isbn).group(:genre).order("id_count DESC")
```

**Detail:**

- ISBN is a 13 char. string, but I'd like to group by the first two characters.
- Example: if there are two strings, `ab1234568901` and `ab98765432109`, I'd like them to be grouped because they both start with `ab`
- I've tried replacing `.group(:isbn)` with `.group(:isbn[0,2])` but then it looks for a column named `is` (the first two char's of `isbn`) and fails out.
- Note: I want to keep the whole isbn in the db because it's possible we want to later on group by the first 4, 6, etc. digits.

**Question:**

- How do I transform this query to do everything it's currently doing, but only group by the first two characters of isbn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```rb
BookSearch.select(
  "count(book_id) as id_count, short_name, genre", 
  "LEFT(book_searches.isbn,2) AS isbn_selector"
).limit(5)
 .where(created_at: time_range)
 .group(:short_name)
 .group("isbn_selector")
 .group(:genre)
 .order("id_count DESC")
```

Comment: This [Left() function] works perfectly! Thank you